# Getting Data from a Weather API to a Twitter Bot

Tags: node.js, json

I'm setting up a Twitter bot to tweet out a city's temperature, I got the API but I can't seem to hook it on my bot.js file

I tried changing the variables but nothing seems to work.

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);


 gotData();


     function setup() {

         loadJSON("http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=7165704df08340e9b00213540192507&q=Colombo", gotData);

    }


    function gotData(data) {
        console.log('Weather Data Retrieved...')

    var r = data.current[2];

    var tweet = {
      status: 'here is ' + r + ' temperature test '
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet);

}
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

Comment: replace gotData(); to setup();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `gotData()` does not pass a `data` argument so when the `gotData` function attempts to access `data.current[2]` `data` is undefined. By the looks of your code you just need to change the line `gotData();` to `setup();`